# Why when making sum of int variable + int variable i'm getting two numbers as result?

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
    label13.Text = e.failedUrls + doneWebPages.ToString();
}));
```

The result is: 01,02,03,04.....09,111

When e.failedUrls is for example 1 now and doneWebPages is 22 so instead showing me in label13 the sum 23 i see 122.

What is wrong ?

Comment: Well they are both strings. What do you think happens when you add two strings together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're adding an `int` to a `string`<sup>1</sup>. The rules of the language will cause the compiler to emit instructions to convert<sup>2</sup> the `int` to a `string`, and thus you are seeing `string` concatenation. Thus

if `e.failedUrls` is `1`, as you say, and `doneWebPages` is `22`, also as you say, then

```
e.failedUrls + doneWebPages.ToString()
```

will result in

```
1.ToString() + "22"
```

which will result in

```
"1" + "22"
```

which is `"122"`, as you're seeing. If you want integer arithmetic, what you want is:

```
label13.Text = (e.failedUrls + doneWebPages).ToString();
```

That is, *first* add the numbers, and *then* call `ToString` on the result.

<sup>1</sup>: I'm assuming that `e.failedUrls` is an `int` because you seem to think it's an `int`. Obviously, `doneWebPages.ToString()` is a `string`, but I'm assuming that `doneWebPages` is an  `int` since you also seem to think it's an `int`.

<sup>2</sup>: There is an operator `+` defined on `String` with parameters `+(object x, string y)`. The semantics of `+` are

```
x + y -> x != null ? (x.ToString() ?? "") + y : "" + y;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're adding a number and a string.

- `e.failedUrls` seems to be a number, judging from your description.
- `doneWebPages.ToString()` is a string.

So, `5 + "13"` equals `"513"`.

To fix this, remove the `.ToString()` call from the second operand. Then you'll have something like `5 + 13`, which equals `18`.

Answer (score 1):

You're concatenating strings.  Convert to Int32 first using `Int32.Parse()`, or `Int32.TryParse()`

Answer (score 1):

You are adding two `string`s together.  You need to use `int.Parse` to cast them to `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

Quite some information is missing from your question to be sure, but let's assume the straightforward:

Let's say `failedUrls` and `doneWebPages` are integers. Then the expression

```
label13.Text = e.failedUrls + doneWebPages.ToString();
```

is evaluated from inside out.

That is, the following sub-expressions get evaluated:

- `e.failedUrls` -> a number
- `doneWebPages` -> a number
- `doneWebPages.ToString()` -> a string, representing the aforementioned number
- `e.failedUrls + doneWebPages.ToString()` -> concatenates a number and a string

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not that familiar with C#, it seems that since, when invoking "+" method, you are converting doneWebPages to a string via the ToString() method, you are using the "+" method in the context of string concatenation as opposed to addition.  Try converting e.failedUrls and doneWebPages to integers before assigining a value to label13.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding two strings not two integer

Answer (score 0):

The + operator is overloaded for strings, it causes string concatenation.

You used e.failedUrls + doneWebPages.ToString(). Since the second parameter is a string, .NET took a string representation of the first and concatenated the strings.

So "1" + "22" = "122".

If you want addition, make sure both the operands are int / numbers. Try converting doneWebPages to a integer representation.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are adding two string values , You must add two integer values instead

```
label13.Text = int.Parse(e.failedUrls.ToString() + int.Parse( doneWebPages.ToString())
```

this way will solve your problem